# Can't find any modules in Django project

Tags: django, python-3.x

I've been following a Django tutorial and initially created virtualenv and a requirements file in it. Project was halfway and in working state. Today I activated virtualenv successfully and tried `python manage.py runserver` to get error

```
 ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

I realized it's not finding Django and just to be sure checked my `requirements.txt` file (which confirmed right Django version). Tried to reinstall it from the file using `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` (tried using just pip too) to get another error --

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

It seems the environment is unable to find any of the modules. I tried to reinstall `pip` also just to be sure, but then it couldn't find apt-get command.

OS: Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11.6

Python: 3.6.2

Django: 1.10.3 (in requirements file)

Comment: You should run `pip` at the command line, not inside Python shell.

Comment: @Selcuk I ran it in command line only. Those are the errors from CL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running [`python -m ensurepip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html) (or `python3 -m ensurepip`) to see if pip is already installed:

> In most cases, end users of Python shouldn’t need to invoke this module directly (as pip should be bootstrapped by default), but it may be needed if installing pip was skipped when installing Python (or when creating a virtual environment) or after explicitly uninstalling pip.